# How to handle private data in Android Studio Projects?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm currently developing an app and I want to make it open source. But it uses some data I don't want to share, such as `signing configs` or `api credentials` and so on.

I found a solution for `signing configs` in [this](https://www.timroes.de/2013/09/22/handling-signing-configs-with-gradle/) post. There the `signing config` data is extracted and stored outside of the repo and can be applied using "apply from" in build script.

Now I had the idea to inject my sensitive data the same way using build script extra properties, `metadata` or `buildconfig` variables. But they don't get applied. I found some older blogposts where it's done this way, but I also found some resouces saying gradle changed to not allow it any more. So that's what I discovered: I can inject everything when it's defined in my `build.gradle`, but as soon as I want to inject it from an external gradle file it doesn't work any more.

I know, I can define additional source folders which are outside the repositiory, but that will prevent others from building the project when they fork my repo.

So my question is: What's the best approach to have an open source project, but use private data to build and publish the project using some private data needed to run it properly? I'm using `Android Studio 1.5.1` and `build tools 23.0.2`.

Answer (score 2):

Define project properties such as

```
APP_KEYSTORE=/path/to/keystore
APP_KEYSTORE_PWD=pwd
APP_KEY_ALIAS=alias
APP_KEY_PWD=pwd
```

in ~/.gradle/gradle.properties

Then use them in build.gradle:

```
if (project.hasProperty('APP_KEYSTORE')) {
    android.signingConfigs.release.storeFile = file(APP_KEYSTORE.toString())
    android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword = APP_KEYSTORE_PWD
    android.signingConfigs.release.keyAlias = APP_KEY_ALIAS
    android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword = APP_KEY_PWD
}
else {
    android.buildTypes.release.signingConfig = null
}
```

This lets everyone use their own signing keys for release builds if that's needed.

You can further inject data from gradle.properties for use in the app via buildConfigField and resValue:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        buildConfigField, 'String' 'CONFIG_NAME', '"' + CONFIG_PROPERTY + '"'
        resValue, 'string', 'CONFIG_NAME', CONFIG_PROPERTY
    }
}
```

buildConfig will create a member in the app's generated BuildConfig class called CONFIG_NAME with the value defined in the gradle property CONFIG_PROPERTY.  Note the quoting required for string value - not needed for other types.

resValue will create a string resource that will get added just like any other resource in the app.

These are discussed briefly in the [gradle build system doc](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system).

However, be careful about putting values like API keys into your app like this because they will be essentially visible to anyone who cares to disassemble your APK.

Comment: as mentioned, signing is not the problem any more - the solution in the blopost I linked worked great. but how to handle additional private data such as api or server keys

Comment: Sorry, it's a similar mechanism, and I edited the answer to include that as well.

Comment: thats exactly what I tried before: when I do this in my main gradle everythng works great, but when I try to imprt it via "gradle apply" from another file it doesn't work

Comment: You don't use `apply` with gradle.properties.  Its definitions are automatically made available throughout the build.

Comment: So how should gradle know my file when it's located in another folder?

Comment: The definitions in $HOME/.gradle/gradle.properties are picked up by default in every gradle build.  You don't have to do anything special.

Answer (score 0):

Dougs answer pointed me to a working solution. Extra properties ext{...} can't be loaded any more, but I was able to load values from a properties file.

```
project.ext.apiKey = "";

// extra properties
if(new File(extrasFile).exists()) {
    Properties properties = new Properties()
    properties.load(new FileInputStream(extrasFile))

    project.ext.apiRootUrl = properties.getProperty("apiKey")
}

defaultConfig {
        ...
        buildConfigField "String", "API_KEY", project.ext.apiRootUrl
}
```

Now my buildconfig fields are populated correctly.